# Calculate the hours to reach from source to destination?

Tags: time-series

Assume that

`source` = `A`

`Destination` = `b`

```
distance between A to B is 100 mile .
```

**QUESTION 1**

If a vehicle runs at the speed of the `distance remaning` then how many hours it will take to reach destination `[assume vehicle starts at the speed of 100mile.hr]`

**QUESTION2**

Calculate the time from A to B if the speed the the `distance covered` [`starting speed is 0 mile/hr`]

Comment: I don't understand. In question 1 you say "speed of distance remaining". But distance remaining is a distance, not a speed...

Comment: And question 2 makes even less sense to me. Can you make both clearer. Also, you haven't used an appropriate tag.

Comment: @JoeTait If my understanding is okay then in Q1 the vehicle will have a speed of $x$ miles an hour at the moment that the destination is $x$ miles ahead.

Comment: yes H.B is correst @joitait

Comment: @SNEHPANDYA and the second question?

Comment: inverse of that starting with the `speed`= `distance covered`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is meant as a comment, but reputation lacks.
Q1
Every moment of his journey he has at least one hour to go. The vehicle will never arrive.
Q2
Starting with speed $0$ we will stay in the startposition forever.